# запрет доступа к папкам средством .htaccess на web сервере

Tags: .htaccess

нужно на сервере запретить доступ к некоторым папкам, но так что бы скрипты могли с ними работать

Comment: Напишите ваш вопрос подробнее. Если убрать тег, то вообще непонятно о каком сервере идет речь. Можно подумать что это, к примеру, windows-сервер и вы хотите запретить доступ по протоколу SMB или еще много чего можно нафантазировать.

Comment: сам тег .htaccess подразумевает куда запретить доступ, кто не знает этого тот не ответит как бы не был четко сформулирован вопрос

Comment: ИМХО данный сайт сделан не только для того чтобы один человек задал вопрос и получил ответ, но и для того чтобы решение можно было найти поиском не задавая вопрос повторно. Вы ведь не просто из интереса задаете вопрос. Наверное вы уже почитали документацию и вопрос не является тривиальным (каким он выглядит сейчас)

Answer (score 1):

В директории, куда необходимо закрыть доступ создайте файл `.htaccess` с содержанием:

`order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

где,

`order deny,allow` - определяет порядок предоставления доступа

`deny from all` - запрещаем доступ для всех

`allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` - разрешаем доступ для своего ip

Comment: так не будут работать скрипты которые обращаются к файлам тех папок, как запретить доступ к просмотру вот например Options All -Indexes, но это для того файла где .htaccess, как рекурсию сделать?

Comment: Скрипты обращаются к этим файлам через HTTP?

Comment: да через него самого, в корневой папке лежит .htaccess, в нем прописан Options All -Indexes, localhost/sait/papka/ оно блокирует для просмотра, но если зайти по localhost/sait/papka/papka2 не блокирует

Comment: а нет блокирует, просто из papka2 нужно было index.html убрать

Comment: если скрипты обращаются по http, то можно разрешить доступ к папке `allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, вместо xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx подставить 127.0.0.1 и/или внешний ip сервера с которого обращаются скрипты